# canonical-kubernetes disappeared?

Tags: conjure-up, kubernetes

I'm following the instructions at [The charmed distribution of kubernetes](https://jaas.ai/canonical-kubernetes)

But seems that the kubernetes spell doesn't exist

```
sysop@kvmnode1:~$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
[sudo] password di sysop: 
conjure-up 2.6.7-20190521.1305 from Canonical✓ installed
sysop@kvmnode1:~$ conjure-up canonical-kubernetes
[error] Can't find a spell matching 'canonical-kubernetes'
```

How can I install kubernetes using conjure-up?

Comment: What happens if you just run conjure-up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunate. I'll file a bug with the `conjure-up` team. Charmed Kubernetes recently rebranded from Canonical Kubernetes. It's possible that the spell name has also been updated without changing the documentation.

In the meantime, you can run `conjure-up` interactively. It knows the right spell to cast.

```
$ conjure-up
```

[image: Screenshot of running conjure-up directly]

That gives you the advantage of being able to customise your installation. Here is the next page of the output:

[image: Screenshot of options available after selecting Charmed Kubernetes in conjure-up]

Answer (score 2):

conjure-up does not work either for me

```
Problem getting channel information: <Response [500]>                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                        Review log messages at /home/grizzlysmit/.cache/conjure-up/conjure-up.log If appropriate, please submit a bug here: https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/new
```